# Input and output in latex algorithm

Tags: algorithms, algorithmicx, algorithmic, pseudocode, algpseudocode

In latex, I am writing a pseudocode where I want to have output (of input and output) in the following fashion: [image]

This is my code:

```
\documentclass[sigconf]{acmart}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\usepackage{algorithm}
\usepackage{algpseudocode}
\begin{document}
\begin{algorithm}\label{algo:ProclivityProp2}
\caption{Graph}
\begin{algorithmic}
    \State Input T matrix of measurements 
    \State Output  $\hat X$ \quad matrix of graph signals\\
                   $\hat W$ \quad matrix of outliers\\
\end{algorithmic}
\end{algorithm}
\end{document}
```

And this is my output:[image: My output]

When I use \Input{..} or \Output{..} in my code, I get the following error:

```
! Undefined control sequence.<recently read> \Input \Input  
! Undefined control sequence \Output
```

How can I get the desired output (the first picture)?

Comment: Don't think this is a duplicate question because this one is implicitly asking how to align the text for multiple inputs

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It is easiest to produce output where the "Input" and "Output" headings are on lines of their own, which may be good enough for your purposes:

[image: Sample output]

```
\documentclass[sigconf]{acmart}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\usepackage{algorithm}
\usepackage{algpseudocode}

\algblock{Input}{EndInput}
\algnotext{EndInput}
\algblock{Output}{EndOutput}
\algnotext{EndOutput}
\newcommand{\Desc}[2]{\State \makebox[2em][l]{#1}#2}

\begin{document}
\begin{algorithm}\label{algo:ProclivityProp2}
\caption{Graph}
\begin{algorithmic}
  \Input
  \Desc{T}{matrix of measurements}
  \EndInput
  \Output
  \Desc{$\hat X$}{matrix of graph signals}
  \Desc{$\hat W$}{matrix of outliers}
  \EndOutput
\end{algorithmic}
\end{algorithm}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Is there a way to make the \Desc command add correct amount of white-space if the description text is longer then what fits on the first row?

Comment: @Baraliuh You could replace the `#2` in the definition of `\Desc` by something like `\parbox[t]{some width}{#2}`.